# VersionConflict between tdqm==4.11.2 and twine==1.11.0 python

Tags: python-3.x, twine

When building a python project in Jenkins I have following packages installed:

```
tdqm==4.11.2
twine==1.11.0
```

later on when i try to invoke

```
twine upload -r my_pypi --skip-existing dist/*
```

i get **twine upload -r my_pypi --skip-existing dist/* VersionConflict: tqdm 4.11.2** I cannot change tdqm version because it is used by other projects. Does anyone know the solution to this one?

Answer (score 0):

Installing

```
tqdm==4.11.2
twine==1.9.1
```

solved the problem.